# How do I bind a xaml storyboard to a custom control's Point property in WP7?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7

I am trying to cause a Grid (and all the controls on it) to shake in my WP7 app. Seems the best way to offset the grid is using the Margin property, but there is no ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames supported in WP7 so I can't do it directly.

Instead, I have created a custom control:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace MyNamespace
{
  // Grid which has an OriginOffset property that is tied to the margin,
  // and thus can be animated.

  public class OffsettableGrid : Grid
  {
    public OffsettableGrid()
    {
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty OriginOffsetProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register(
        "OriginOffset", typeof(Point), typeof(OffsettableGrid), null);

    public Point OriginOffset
    {
      get
      {
        return new Point(Margin.Left, Margin.Top);
      }
      set
      {
        Margin = new Thickness(value.X, value.Y,
          Margin.Right, Margin.Bottom);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and then in xaml I declare a storyboard as follows:

```
<Storyboard x:Name="m_shakeStoryboard" 
            RepeatBehavior="5x" 
            AutoReverse="False" 
            SpeedRatio="5">

    <PointAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
        BeginTime="00:00:00"
        Storyboard.TargetName="m_chooseAnswerGrid"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(OffsettableGrid.OriginOffset)">

        <EasingPointKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00"    Value="0,0"/>
        <EasingPointKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2"  Value="-10,0"/>
        <EasingPointKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.4"  Value="10,0"/>
        <EasingPointKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.6"  Value="0,0"/>
    </PointAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

</Storyboard>
```

and then of course I declare my grid using .

But when I go to start the storyboard:

```
m_shakeStoryboard.Begin();
```

my OriginOffset property never gets invoked. I put a breakpoint at "Margin = new Thickness(value.X, value.Y," but it never gets hit. What am I doing wrong?

In the editor, whenever I change OriginOffset, the margins change as well as expected.

Any help much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Doesn't OriginOffset need to be a DependencyProperty to support data binding?

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks. I've got past the exception, but nothing happens... Updated code snippets above. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dependency property is not well defined. You should use SetValue and GetValue:

```
public Point OriginOffset
{
   get
   {
       return (Point)GetValue(OriginOffsetProperty);
   }
   set
   {
       SetValue(OriginOffsetProperty, value);
   }
}
```

Then add a callback to the PropertyMetadata of the dependency property, to set the margin:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty OriginOffsetProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "OriginOffset", 
        typeof(Point), 
        typeof(OffsettableGrid), 
        new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnOriginOffsetChanged)));
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard.targetproperty.aspx) out.  Aren't you going to have to use an EventTrigger or something to start the StoryBoard?  And I don't think you need the parenthesis's, `Storyboard.TargetProperty="(OffsettableGrid.OriginOffset)"`

```
          <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">    
            <BeginStoryboard>
              <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation 
                  Storyboard.TargetName="myAnimatedBrush"
                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                  From="Red" To="Blue" Duration="0:0:7" />
              </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
          </EventTrigger>
```

Comment: Can't I just use the Begin() call to manually start it in code as I showed above? Any idea my breakpoint is not being hit? Seems that the animation is not making any attempt to change the value of OriginOffset.

Comment: Yeah, Begin will work.  Do you need to call InitializeComponent in the constructor of your user control?

Comment: Make the TargetProperty="OriginOffset"

Comment: No, doing so gives a compile error that it doesn't know the symbol. I am deriving from Grid not UserControl, so perhaps this has something to do with it, and I'm assuming that Grid's constructor will take care of that anyways. In the editor, my derived OffsettableGrid component functions as expected. It's just that the settings of the OriginOffset via the Storyboard does nothing...

Comment: When I'm able to get on a PC I'll try and re create.

Comment: Same thing happens (nothing) with TargetProperty="OriginOffset" :(

Comment: That would be awesome! Thanks. I also tried putting in a Test property that's just a plain double, but same problem occurs: nothing happens when the storyboard is launched and the property's set handler is never called.

Comment: I've started a bounty for this :)